# How do I check, if an array is defined as key value pairs?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function, that takes an array as an argument.

```
function addSearch($arr) { }
```

How can I check in that function whether the array was defined just with values

```
array('option1', 'option2', ...);
```

or as key-value pairs:

```
array('option1' => 'First Option', 'option2' => 'Second Option', ...)
```

What I like to achive, is that you could either pass the search fileds along with labels, or just the search fields, in which case the field name will also become the label.

So I need to change an array, that has just values to `$array['option1'] = 'option1'`;

Any ideas how to achive this?

Comment: Why don't you pass other parameter ?

Comment: Your best bet would be to pass an object whose task is to determine whether the array is key:value or just value. Then invoking get() function of the object, you'd get corresponding value (label, value, null in case it's malformed etc.). That way you'd shift checking whether your array is fine to a separate container.

Comment: Such an "improvement" (two ways of passing data) will actually lead to confusion and hardships

Comment: @RicardoLohmann: That's possible, but it puts the burden on the calling code. Imagine for instance that the array gets passed along through a series of functions: each will need to include the additional parameter. If there's a way to figure it out within the function that actually needs to know, it can make for a much cleaner interface.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: This is extremely common in PHP (and other languages without strict typing). It's essentially just polymorphism, but all wrapped into a single function body. I would argue it makes it less confusing for the client (whoever is calling your function) because they don't need to figure out which variant of the function to call, and they don't need to keep track of what type of data they have (for instance, if it was passed in from somewhere else).

Comment: Strange comment, the last one

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm I dislike that approach. Nobody knows what kind of data they're dealing with and it all just gets passed along until some sorry sod has to figure it out, which grows into hundreds of lines of code just to normalize some unknown data structure into something sane again.

Comment: @deceze: I see your point, but it's still a very common approach to making a function simpler for the people who are actually using it. Take a look at any python function that accepts either a path to a file, or a file-like object. Or for that matter, the `+` operator in basically any language which can work with at least ints and floats (and often strings). The "sorry sod" who is writing the library function is the one who is deciding to support multiple formats (or someone on their team, anyway), so it's their call if they're willing to put in the one time effort to do so.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm Accepting two decidedly different *types* is fine and in many languages even supported by syntactic sugar (being able to define both `foo(int bar)` and `foo(string bar)`). But passing arbitrary arrays of an unknown structure around is asking for trouble. *"Oh, you can pass in just values. Or keyed values. Or arrays of arrays with keyed or unkeyed values. Or a mix of both. Or nothing."* The code that has to deal with that is bound to be horrible.

Comment: @deceze: Meh. Other than your RAA, it's a matter of taste. I say if the library author is willing to put in the effort to do the type checking in a sane way, then more power to them for taking the burden of their users.

Comment: I find it odd that someone would argue that *not* having a safe data source is bad. It's actually stupid to claim that. I'd always create an object that gives me **exactly** what I need (or fails) rather than transform an array in a function that uses it. But that's just me. I like simple stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot know how an array was *defined*. Both kinds of arrays are the same thing, they both have keys and values. The difference is that the "keyless array" uses auto-generated *numeric keys*, while in the other example keys are explicitly given as strings. These two arrays are identical:

```
array('option1', 'option2')
array(0 => 'option1', 1 => 'option2')
```

You can even mix both:

```
array('foo', 'bar' => 'baz', 42 => 'qux')
```

Therefore, what you're really interested in is whether the key is a string:

```
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    if (is_string($key)) {
        // string => value pair
    } else {
        // numerically indexed pair
        // note: could still have been explicitly defined, who knows?
    }
}
```

Comment: array('0' => 'option1', '1' => 'option2')

Comment: @You I never said what the OP wants to do makes any sense. On the contrary, I'm trying to highlight how arbitrary arrays really are.

Comment: @deceze: Thanks, thats what I assumed. I now ended up walking the array and checking with is_string(), for any non-string. And only if none of the array keys is a string, I rewrite the array.

Answer (score 3):

this will check if your array is associative

```
function is_associative($array) {
    return array_values($array) !== $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
<?php
function isAssociative($arr)
{
    return array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to go with @phranx on this one.

Let's say you have this 
**array('1'=>'Under', '2'=>'Over')**

The keys in this array will be evaluated as integers.

The best way is to determine if the keys are **key:values** pairs is to check if the ***values*** of the array are ***equal*** to the array itself.