# Check if a particular array key is sequential in an array with mixed sequential and associative entries

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array like:

```
$array = [
    'value1',
    71,
    'stringKey' => 'value2',
    3 => 'value3',
    4 => 'value4',
    64 => 'value5',
    'value6',
];
```

I want to loop through the entries and do a different thing depending on whether the entry has a key "manually set" (e.g., `64 => 'value5'`), or it's just a value with a "sequential" key (e.g., `'value1'` - which is actually `0 => 'value1'`).

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (/* $key has not been "manually set" (i.e., is "sequential") */) {
        $result[$value] = 'default';
    } else {
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

So my resulting array would be:

```
[
    'value1' => 'default',
    71 => 'default',
    'stringKey' => 'value2',
    3 => 'value3',
    4 => 'value4',
    64 => 'value5',
    'value6' => 'default',
]
```

I have been trying with `array_keys()`, checking if `is_numeric($key)`, but nothing works for all the entries above.

I'm starting to think this is actually impossible...

Comment: is it not 'value6' => 'default' in your expected result. I want to know, why your expect this transform?

Comment: @KrisRoofe yes sorry, edited.

Comment: I would say that the question is unclear. In reality, the last item is `65 => 'value6'`, so the items `4 => 'value4'` and `65 => 'value6'` have equal right  to become ``'value4' => 'default'`` and `'value6' => 'default'`.

Comment: Further more, where this $array comes. If your define it this, why not you directly define the result, If it's not defined manually, how can you make index [0, 1] and index [3, 4] apart?

Comment: @KrisRoofe I didn't want to explain the whole scenario, but yeah that array is a possible input of my function - the integers are IDs of things and the strings are names of things; and each array entry sometimes is just a ID/name, and sometimes is pair of ID/name and a sub-config... (the array is bigger and more nested in reality)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yeah ok so as I was thinking, basically the way PHP works it doesn't matter whether you specify a key or not, it will be considered _exactly_ the same, and there's no way to know...

Comment: I don't it's possible to make if.  Refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18125360/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == $i) {
        $result[$value] = 'default';
    } else {
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
    if (is_integer($key) && $key >= $i) $i = (int)$key + 1;
}
```

However, it will treat `4 => 'value4'` differently from what you had indicated, because the input array would be *exactly* the same if you would have put just `'value4'`. There is no way to determine from the array whether you had explicitly mentioned the key 4 or omitted the key.

So the above code treats this key/value pair in the same way that it treats the last key/value pair.

The output is:

```
array (
  'value1' => 'default',
  71 => 'default',
  'stringKey' => 'value2',
  3 => 'value3',
  'value4' => 'default',
  64 => 'value5',
  'value6' => 'default',
)
```

Comment: he has no `'value4' => 'default',` within expected result

Comment: note, I didn't downvote, but I also think that the answer is "out-of-place". The issue is obvious

Comment: obviously doesn't solve my problem but +1 for "There is no way to determine from the array whether you had explicitly mentioned the key 4 or omitted the key.", which is the actual answer